# Cannot get the updated field value from database in C#

Tags: database, nhibernate

The below query does not getting the updated data from the database table. It simply shows the data that was before existing. It is not getting a newly updated data for the same id in the datatable.

```
public Sample GetSampleStreamId(int id)
        {
            return session.CreateQuery("from Sample sd where sd.Id = :id")
                          .SetParameter("id", id)
                          .List<Sample>().SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

Comment: You'd provide more details. This kind of method will never return "stale" data, unless there are other circumstances. How are data changed? directly in DB, in different session? is there cache in place? why are you not using session.Get<>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the below code to close the session.
It will retrieve the the data updated in the database

```
Session.Close();
```